# How to delete whole python and reinstall?

Tags: macos, python, sublime-text-2

I have set the python window size wrong. I set the width to something like 99999 and caused a crash. Since then, I tried to delete every package installed with python, and then reinstall, but this has not solved the problem.

Now I cannot use python IDLE anymore. What can I do? What's the file that contains the window size information? Can I change the python window size outside of python IDLE somehow?

I tried to delete the framework and reinstall. But somehow the crash report stopped showing up anymore. I just cannot open python IDLE. I can still use python in Terminal, and I can use textWrangler.

Things I deleted:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
```

With the help of another post, I can now use Sublime again, but Python IDLE still won't work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a program to clean out your registry of unused programs like CCleaner after you have unistalled the program.  Often many programs leave files in the registry even after they have been uninstalled.  Here is a link to the download of the program:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/ccleaner/dl/189/

Comment: OP is using OS X...